# Rails 4 - Heroku deploy works but images in CSS file do not appear

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have tried multiple ways to get some images to show up that are embedded in my style.css.erb file upon a Heroku deploy. I have no problems with the images showing up locally just upon deploy so I am assuming this is due to the precompiled assets. Here is what I have, any help/advice is much appreciated:

style.css.erb

```
#parallax1{ 
  background-image:url('<%= asset_path("parallax/1.jpg")%>');
}

#parallax2{ 
  background-image:url('<%= asset_path("parallax/2.jpg")%>');
}

#intro{
position: relative; 
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
height:650px;
z-index:2;
background-image: url('<%= asset_path("bgslides/3.jpg")%>');
background-size:cover;
}
```

production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.js bootstrap.min.js jquery.nav.js jquery.scrollTo.js grid.js custom.js stellar.js modernizr.custom.js jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js wow.min.js mb.bgndGallery.effects.js mb.bgndGallery.js font-awesome.css.scss.erb animate.css bootstrap.min.css simpletextrotator.css style.css.erb *.jpg *.png )
```

assets.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.js bootstrap.min.js jquery.nav.js jquery.scrollTo.js grid.js custom.js stellar.js modernizr.custom.js jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js wow.min.js mb.bgndGallery.effects.js mb.bgndGallery.js font-awesome.css.scss.erb animate.css bootstrap.min.css simpletextrotator.css style.css.erb *.jpg *.png )
```

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module DryerPlug
 class Application < Rails::Application
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this        zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
 end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:                
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: Inspect the CSS on your deployed application. What path is it trying to use to find the images?

Comment: it is trying to find them in heroku_app_name.herokuapp.com/assets/bgslides/1.jpg. It is missing the images folder entirely. Not sure if that tells you anything...

Comment: Have you tried doing a manual `heroku run rake assets:precompile`? Always worth a try.

Comment: Yep that seems to succeed. It is finding the asset path but not the fingerprinted version it seems.

Comment: Have a look here: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#dependencies-improperly-used](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#dependencies-improperly-used). Before that though, you may want to try doing a `bundle update` because there was [something related changed in sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/126) semi-recently.

Answer (score 4):

**SCSS**

The problem you have is you're calling a ruby-on-rails `erb` methods in your `CSS` - which, although feasible, will likely cause a multitude of problems down the line

A much better way to resolve this is to use one of the Rails CSS [preprocessors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) so your application can precompile the assets properly. The typical CSS preprocessor is `SCSS`:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
#parallax1{ 
  background-image: asset_url("parallax/1.jpg");
}
```

--

**Precompile**

You need to keep your stylesheets 100% CSS (or SCSS) - as when you `precompile` them (required for deploying to Heroku), Rails won't be able to use much of the logic / functionality an `erb` file would create

Although you are correct when you've used the `erb` functionality, the best way is to use the `SCSS` preprocessor. On top of this, you need to ensure you've precompiled your assets locally:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Precompiled"
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try compiling the assets locally? That is what usually what works for me.

First clean the current assets

```
rake assets:clean
```

Then precompile them again

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Then commit these assets and push to Heroku. If this doesn't work, try to run in in production mode by adding `RAILS_ENV=production` to each command.